# Multiple Zend Multicheckbox same name

Tags: zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a Zend_Form with multiple Multicheckbox element, the thing that I want is to give them all the same name: categories[].
When I add multiple elements like this:

```
 $this->createElement('multiCheckbox', 'categories[]')
    ->setLabel('Category 1')
    ->addMultiOption(1, 'Subcat1')

 $this->createElement('multiCheckbox', 'categories[]')
    ->setLabel('Category 2')
    ->addMultiOption(2, 'Subcat2')
    etc...
```

Only the Category 2 checkboxes are displayed.

Seems that Zend has the element name as leading. Currently I workaround this with different element names but this isn't really workable at all.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended splitting them up in separate groups.

Answer (score 0):

that's not how you use multiCheckbox,
use

```
$multicheckbox->addMultiOptions($zone);
```

see here a similar example [addmultioption array problem in Zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571009/addmultioption-array-problem-in-zend)

Comment: if you want to split the multicheckbox, you are gonna have to use viewScripts and manually validate them, i don't believe you can split them with zend_form